# NORMDIST function is not giving the correct output

Tags: excel, excel-formula, statistics, distribution, normal-distribution

I'm trying to use `NORMDIST` function in Excel to create a bell curve, but the output is strange.

My *mean* is `0,0000583` and *standard deviation* is `0,0100323` so when I plug this to the function `NORMDIST(0,0000583; 0,0000583; 0,0100323; FALSE)`  I expect to get something close to `0,5` as I'm using the same value as the mean probability of this value should be `50%`, but the function gives an output of `39,77` which is clearly not correct.

Why is it like this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A probability cannot have values greater than 1, but a density can.

The integral of the entire range of a density function is equal 1, but it can have values greater than one in specific interval. [Example](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probability_density_function), a uniform distribution on the interval [0, ½] has probability density f(x) = 2 for 0 ≤ x ≤ ½ and f(x) = 0 elsewhere. See below:

[image]            [image]

[image]

[image]

`=NORMDIST(x, mean, dev, FALSE)` returns the density function. Densities are probabilities per unit. It is almost the probability of a point, but with a very tiny range interval (the derivative in the point).

shg's answer [here](http://www.excelforum.com/excel-formulas-and-functions/652580-normdist-function-in-excel-giving-values-greater-than-1-a.html), explain how to get a probability on a given interval with NORMIDIST and also in what occasions it can return a density greater than 1.

> For a continuous variable, the probability of any particular value is zero, because there are an infinite number of values.
>
> If you want to know the probability that a continuous random variable with a normal distribution falls in the range of a to b, use:
>
> =NORMDIST(b, mean, dev, TRUE) - NORMDIST(a, mean, dev, TRUE)
>
> The peak value of the density function occurs at the mean (i.e., =NORMDIST(mean, mean, dev, FALSE) ), and the value is:
>
> =1/(SQRT(2*PI())*dev)
>
> The peak value will exceed 1 when the deviation is less than 1 / sqrt(2pi) ~ 0.399,

which was your case.

This is an amazing [answer](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/4220/a-probability-distribution-value-exceeding-1-is-ok) on Cross Validated Stack Exchange (statistics) from a moderator (whuber), that addresses this issue very thoughtfully.

Answer (score 2):

It is returning the probability density function whereas I think you want the cumulative distribution function (so try TRUE in place of FALSE) [ref](http://office.microsoft.com/en-gb/excel-help/normdist-HP005209192.aspx).

Comment: TRUE will return the CDF which will tell the probability of random variable is < X. Like NORMDIST(0,0000583; 0,0000583; 0,0100323; TRUE) will show the probability of the random variable being less than my mean. I guess i'm just using the wrong formula.

Comment: The documentation uses the term "probability mass function" but it should have said "probability density function".  If you see later in the help, it does say "equation for the normal density function"