# Normal distribution plot in R

Tags: r, plot

I am trying to plot a normal distribution in r using the plot command:

```
plot(x, dnorm(x, mean, sd)),
```

using my values for mean and sd.

However, with these values, the numbers on the y-axis are greater than 1. Since I want a probability density function, is this normal? My values are reasonable otherwise, for example in confidence intervals. Also, the function's shape is reasonable. The axis is the only issue.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about probability. I think it should be migrated to http://stats.stackexchange.com

Comment: See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17953189/normdist-function-not-giving-correct-output/17954201#17954201), and even much better, [here](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/4220/a-probability-distribution-value-exceeding-1-is-ok).

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. I read the comments, but I am still a bit confused how to interpret the numbers on the y-axis in this case? Must my density always be multiplied by a small range?

Comment: The density function of a continuous random variable *does not* return the probability of a value. I suggest you read a good text in probability (I recommend you "A first cours in probability" by Sheldon Ross)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is normal, you're mixing concepts i guess.

For discrete events you can assign a probability for each outcome, which we call `probability mass`. This is a probability, so must be in the range [0, 1].

For continuous outcomes we can **discretize** the space into a set of *bins*, each one holding a interval of your variable. Then you define `probability density`, which is the `probability mass` of a *bin* divided by that *bin* interval.

That's why you can get `probability densities` greater than 1: some big mass of probability inside a small range, like density = mass/volume in physics.

You can get a better answer/explanation at https://stats.stackexchange.com/, good luck!

Answer (score 2):

Even if your density function has values above 1, that doesn't mean it is wrong.

**Example:**

```
x <- seq(-3,3,.001)
y1 <- dnorm(x, 0, 1)    # max(y1) = 0.3989423
y2 <- dnorm(x, 0, 0.5)  # max(y2) = 0.7978846
y3 <- dnorm(x, 0, 0.25) # max(y3) = 1.595769
```

And they are all valid values for the density function. A density function is not required to have values below 1 to be valid, but it's definite integral value ***must*** be 1.

---

**Update**

It is possible to demonstrate that, if *X* is a random variable with Normal distribution *`N(mean, sd)`* and if the standard deviation `sd` is smaller or equal than `1 / sqrt(2 * pi)`, the density function will have at least one value greater than 1. Specifically, if `x=mean` and `sd = 1 / sqrt(2 * pi)` then `f(x) = 1`.